# Minecraft Optifine Lagometer - meaning of white bar?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, performance, minecraft-optifine

I am currently trying to figure out why Minecraft is running extremely slow on a specific computer. So I enabled the lagometer an it shows me a huge white bar. Unfortunately, the meaning of white is not explained in the lagometer tooltip. Can anyone tell me what it means? I am running Minecraft 1.12.2 on Windows 10 with Optifine.
[image]

Comment: How high is your render distance? Seems to be the cause.

Comment: In this screenshot, it was relatively high, 12 I think. But even when I just look down on the floor (which is what I did for the lower bars in the lagometer), the white part makes up most of the lag.

Comment: 12 chunks is a lot, yes. If the computer isn't very good, it will lag with that setting.

Comment: It was probably 8, because the number of total chunk sections starts with 46… 4624 chunk sections are a render distance of 8.

Comment: Even with a render distance of 2 the game doesn't get >20 fps consistently though. But I guess that is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

> The white top of the line shows the time in the world update part of the code. This is where world blocks and entities get updated, for example: mobs spawning, water flowing, redstone working, trees and plants growing etc. The world update is also known as tick and is performed every 50 ms (20 times per second) independent from the screen update rate. This is why on higher FPS not every lag line has a white top, the tick skips some frames to keep the rate of 20 updates per second.

It means that you aren't rendering everything on screen fast enough. Try turning down render distance.

[Source](http://optifog.blogspot.com/2011/08/understanding-minecraft-performance.html)

Comment: I saw that blog post as well, but it is from 2011 and the design has changed. According to the in-game tooltip, cyan now displays the ticks and green the world rendering. I have tried turning down render distance, it helps, but even when I set it to 2 the game lags. Weird thing is, we have an older laptop with similar hardware and the game works just fine.